# Extra White Space in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a Card with just html and CSS and for now the card seems okay but in the text section of the card, I see some extra white space just above the text. Can someone please see as to why i might be getting that?

Here is a [link](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/NWRwaLj) to a working codepen.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  margin: auto;
  border: solid;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card-text {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Let's Create a Card</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Card</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ca/76/0b/ca760b70976b52578da88e06973af542.jpg" alt="My-image" height="300px" width="300px">
    <p class="card-text">Some Text that goes for the card Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed ipsa cum illo accusamus aperiam nulla quam. quae?</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options are to make the `<img>`:

- `display: block` or
- `vertical-align: bottom`

[`<img>`: The Image Embed element - Styling with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Styling_with_CSS)

> `<img>` is a replaced element; it has a display value of inline by default...
> `<img>` has no baseline, so when images are used in an inline formatting context with vertical-align: baseline, the bottom of the image will be placed on the text baseline.

So depending on the `font`, `font-size` and `line-height` styles inherited from the parent element, some space will be reserved for ascenders and descenders of possibly adjacent text.

You can read more about this [here](https://dev.to/christiankaindl/the-strange-img-gap-in-html).

`display: block;`

```css
.container {
  border: solid;
  width: 300px;
}

.card-text {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ca/76/0b/ca760b70976b52578da88e06973af542.jpg" alt="My-image" height="300px" width="300px">
  <p class="card-text">Some Text that goes for the card Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed ipsa cum illo accusamus aperiam nulla quam. quae?</p>
</div>
```

`vertical-align: bottom;`

```css
.container {
  border: solid;
  width: 300px;
}

.card-text {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ca/76/0b/ca760b70976b52578da88e06973af542.jpg" alt="My-image" height="300px" width="300px">
  <p class="card-text">Some Text that goes for the card Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed ipsa cum illo accusamus aperiam nulla quam. quae?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. That did the job. Accepting this as an answer.

Comment: And thank you for the explanation. That clears it as to why this was happening.